# Find the sum of given interval?

Tags: java

Ho to find the sum of given interval?
For example sum of 1 to 10 or 11 to 30?

Comment: you mean sum of integers? Sound like a homework, what have you tried so far.

Comment: This Wikipedia article offers the formula you need: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation

Comment: The answer involves simple math that you can do in your head. Why do you need a program for this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum

Answer (score 6):

Generally it is `N * (first + last) / 2`

Comment: +1 for general answer.
full details and explanation on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find the sum of numbers from 1 to N

```
int summation = (N*N + N)/2;
```

The function would be:

```
//computes summation from 1 to N
public int summation(int N){
    return (N*N+N)/2;
}
```

Now to find the summation from k and N, we simply firn `summation(N)` - `summation(K)`

```
public int summation(int K, int N){
    return summation(N)-summation(K);
}
```

---

Comment: +1 for not giving away the entire answer. This offers _part_ of the solution while still forcing them to _think_.

Comment: this solution is useless after the OP's edit. he wants k to n, and not 1 to N.

Comment: oh really? I think k to n is summation(n) - summation(k) ? what do you think?

Comment: then write it in your answer. p.s. its sum(n)-sum(k-1), you do need to include k.

Comment: just realized that was supposed to be a hint and not an answer.  I take my comment back.

Comment: I edited the answer (: I think now it is an answer

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty!

```
int sum = 0;
int start = 1;
int end = 10
for(i=start; i<=end; i++){
    sum += i;
}
```

Note: this sample assumes 10 is inclusive in the range as in [1, 10] and not [1, 10)

Comment: if this is indeed what the OP wants to do, it is overkill. can be done in O(1).

Comment: True, hence the quick and dirty(without too much thought) @Sherif's answer is more thought out!

Comment: this is not quick. it requires 6 lines of code. @AlexR solution is generalized, O(1) and easiest to program.

Comment: This is one line of code buddy... `for(i=1; i<=10; i++){sum += i;}`

Comment: sum = (elemets/2)*(start+end) is both more elegant and better performance. no reason to loop. if you'll need to calculate fibonachi number of nth element, you will do it with simple recursion (which is O(2^n)) or used the well defined closed formula for it (and get a result instantly for n=10000)

Comment: I get what you mean and I'm not saying my code is better... you know what, let me rephrase...quick and dirty == the quickest snippet of code that came to my mind without consideration for speed or performance. It doesn't necessarily have to be the best piece of code as you have pointed out and I have agreed on.

Answer (score 0):

```
int start = 1;
int end = 10;
int sum = 0;

for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
sum+=i;
}
System.out.println("Sum is" + sum);
```

Another Approach :

```
while(end > start) {
sum+=start++;
}
System.out.println("Sum is" + sum);
```

Or you can use 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a homework, and I think you are so beginner in Java. Then I just can help you with these tips:

1. You may use a for loop which will iterate from the first number to the last
2. You may have a variable for sum, which should be increased in each iteration of for loop
3. Each Java program should have at least one class. In one of them (and just one) there should be a main function