# Sum of all numbers in a given range with some constraints

Tags: algorithm, math

My objective is to find the sum of all numbers from 4 to 666554 which consists of 4,5,6 and satisfying below constraints.

Constraints on number of times a digit appears

1. Number of time 4 appears in the number <= 1
2. Number of time 5 appears in the number <= 2
3. Number of time 6 appears in the number <= 3

   SUM = 4+5+6+45+46+54+55+56+64+65+66+454+455+.....................+666554.

Simple method is to run a loop and add the numbers made of 4,5 and 6 which is satisfying above constraints.

```
long long sum = 0;
for(int i=4;i <=666554;i++){
   /*check if number contains only 4,5 and 6 and constraints are not violated
     if condition is true then add the number to the sum*/
}
```

But it seems to be inefficient. Checking that the number is made up of 4,5 and 6
and number is not violating the constraints will take time. Is there any way to increase the efficiency. I have tried a lot but no new approach i have found.Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum of all numbers written with particular digits in a given range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285547/sum-of-all-numbers-written-with-particular-digits-in-a-given-range)

Comment: Please don't post a question twice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to come from an ongoing competition https://www.hackerrank.com/w16

Answer (score 3):

You should only examine those consisting of the digits 4,5 and 6, of which there are only a few hundred.

That's not too difficult: In your loop, don't just increase i by 1.

If i % 10 < 6 then you just increase i by 1.

Otherwise, subtract 2 (for example 646 turns into 644, 6 turns into 4); if i < 10 then add 40 and you're done, and if i % 100 < 60 then just increase i by 10 and you are done.

Otherwise, subtract 20 (for example 5466 turned into 5464 then 5444); if i < 100 then add 400 and you're done, and if i % 1000 < 600 then just increase i by 100 and you are done.

And so on and so on. That way, you don't examine about 600,000 numbers but only about 800.

An even better approach is not finding the numbers at all. Let's look at six digit numbers. The digit 4 can be in six positions. The digit 5 can be in (5 * 4) / 2 = 10 positions, the digit 6 must be in the remaining positions. So there are only 60 numbers, containing 60 digits 4, 120 digits 5, 180 digits 6. Each digit turns up in all positions, so the sum is 10 * 444444 + 20 * 555555 + 30 * 666666. You do a similar calculation for 1 .. 5 digits.

Comment: Hi gnasher. Could you provide some pseudocode for this ? Would this work if the number of 6 4 and 5  is gretar than 90 in the constraint.?

Comment: can you please elaborate this line "So there are only 60 numbers, containing 60 digits 4, 120 digits 5, 180 digits 6. Each digit turns up in all positions, so the sum is 10 * 444444 + 20 * 555555 + 30 * 666666"

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way to generate all such number is (as often is, when you need to iterate over some combinatoric objects) to iterate over them recursively. Write a recursive function that, receiving "current" number and in separate variables the counts of 6, 5 and 4 in it, will find all possible endings for this number and calculate their sum. Something like this (pseudocode):

```
func rec(current, n4, n5, n6)   // we have used n4 4's, n5 5's and n6 6's
                                // and formed the number current
                                // Let's account for it and add some more digits 
    if (n4>1)||(n5>2)||(n6>3) return 0   // no numbers satisfy the conditions
    // print "Started ", current, n4, n5, n6   // if you want to debug
    ans = current   // account for current number
    ans += rec(current*10+4, n4+1, n5, n6)   // append 4
    ans += rec(current*10+5, n4, n5+1, n6)   // append 5
    ans += rec(current*10+6, n4, n5, n6+1)   // append 6
    // print "Finished ", current, "answer=", ans   // if you want to debug
    return ans

...
answer = rec(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

This approach is quite simple in both concept and coding, and can be very easily adapted to any new requirements.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. ?

Comment: @GauravShankar, I've added some comments. If you want to understand recursive approach, I suggest you running this code with debug output as shown in the comments in the code.

Comment: Would this work even if the number of 4's 5's and 6 are great than 90

Comment: @GauravShankar, it will be absolutely slow, because it indeed _generates_ each number one by one, and thus if the total amount of such numbers is very big, it will work very slow. In that case, you might find some faster algorithm, though with limited possibilities for generalization.

Answer (score 1):

A « funny » way to do this:

```
l = [{0: [4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]}]
```

Here `l` will contain all the number with `n` digits, i.e. `l[0]` contains number with « 0 » digit (kind of philosophical... ), `l[1]` with one digit, etc. `l[n]` is in fact a dict where the keys are the number themselves, and the value the list of available number to continue the algorithm (but what is the algorithm?!).

```
def run (l, n = None):
    if n is None:
        n = len(l[0][0])
    if n == 0:
        return l
    d = {}
    for k, r in l[-1].items(): # Retrieve the last column of l (the largest number)
        # k is the number, r the remaining values
        for i, v in enumerate(r):
            d[10 * k + v] = r[:i] + r[i+1:]
    l.append(d)
    return run (l, n - 1)
```

Then the result is the sum of all the keys of all the dict in l:

```
l = run([{0: [4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]}])
r = sum(map(lambda d: sum(d.keys()), l))
```

---

This is an answer for the discussion in the comment section:

```
def mySum (x, y, z):
    l = [{0: x * [4] + y * [5] + z * [6]}]
    l = run(l)
    return sum(map(lambda d: sum(d.keys()), l))
```

Then you simply do:

```
x, y, z = raw_input().split()
print(mySum(int(x), int(y), int(z)))
```

Comment: Hi! Is there a way that i could modify the frequency of 4 5 and 6 in list l on user input ?

Comment: The allowed numbers and their frequency is defined by the value of the `0` key in the initial list (when you do `run([{0: [... ]}])`. If you specify `[1, 2, 3]` instead of `[4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]`, the new constraint is « All the numbers made of the digits 1, 2, 3 with at most one 1, one 2 and one 3. ».

Comment: Consider the following, the user enters three integers x y and z 
Let the sample input be 
 1 1 1
In this case i want the list l to be l = [{0: [4, 5, 6]}]

In case the input is 1 2 3 i want the list to be like this l = [{0: [4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]}] 
how ?

Comment: @GauravShankar If you are using python, you can simply create your list by doing `x * [4] + y * [5] + z * [6]`, i.e. `1 * [4] + 2 * [5] + 3 * [6] = [4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]`.

Comment: I am newbie in python. Here is what i have been trying.

l = [{0: []}]
x,y,z = raw_input().split()
l[0] = int(x) * [4] + int(y) * [5] + int(z) * [6]

It's not working. Please help! :(

Comment: @GauravShankar What you should do is `x, y, z = raw_input().split()`, then create your `l`: `l = [{0: int(x) * [4] + int(y) * [5] + int(z) * [6]}]`, then `l = run(l)` and then the `sum` as specified in my post. Maybe you could create a function (see my edit).

Comment: Now i should work on improving its complexity. Won't work for 2 digit x y and z's

Comment: @GauravShankar This is not a very efficient algorithm. The idea of starting with one digit number, multiply them by 10, and keep going is good (see also the post of Petr), but if you want an efficient algorithm you should look at the end of gnasher729's post which is a more mathematical approach. Algorithm implying permutation or « growing » approachs (like mine) won't work for large value of `x, y, z`.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the numbers up front, by using permutations. I made a little example for generating all permutations, but in the intermediate loops or in the last loop you can count the numbers of 4's, 5's and 6's. Or create a seperate method for this, but it gives you an idea how to solve this. By using a hashset, you will get unique numbers.

For readability, I suggest you'd rewrite this as a recursive method with a counter on the number of digits.

```
    var numbers = " 456";
    HashSet perm = new HashSet();
    foreach(char n1 in numbers)
    {
        string val1 = Char.ToString(n1);
        if(val1.Substring(0,val1.Length).Contains(" "))
            continue;

        foreach(char n2 in numbers)
        {
            string val2 = val1;
            if(!val1.Substring(0,val1.Length-1).Contains(' '))
                val2 += n2;

            foreach(char n3 in numbers)
            {           
                string val3 = val2;
                if(!val2.Substring(0,val2.Length).Contains(" "))
                    val3 += n3;

                perm.Add(Int32.Parse(val3));
            }
        }
    }
```